Referentiality of "what" in free relatives
The sentence (1a) is ambiguous, as it seems to allow both the interpretation in (1b), where what you ate and what I ordered refer to the same referent, and the interpretation in (1c), where the second what refers to the same kind. Here, I assume this reading of (1c) is just coerced by the situation, that is, a pragmatic interpretation, and that the basic meaning of what in what I ordered is a specific entity, not a kind.
(1)
a. What you ate is what I ordered.
b. The food that you ate is the food that I ordered. (the same referent, e.g., You ate my pasta.)
c. The food that you ate is the same kind of food that I ordered. (the same kind, e.g., I also ate pasta.)
Therefore, what I ordered in (2a) is mostly interpreted as that particular food that I ordered even though both readings may be possible. On the other hand, what you ate in (2b) is interpreted as the kind or type of the food you ate because the fact that it is impossible to order the particular food that someone ate coerces the kind reading.
(2)
a. You ate what I ordered.    (referential reading)
b. I ordered what you ate.    (coerced kind reading)
If we want to convey the kind reading, we use the same one instead of what as in (3).
(3)
a. You ate the same one I ordered.
b. I ordered the same one you ate.
What do you think? Do you agree with my assumption that what used in free relatives basically refers to a specific thing, not a kind?

Yes, you are right. Diners go on to expand on their meaning so they don't eat each other's food orders.

It would be odd to say any of those sentences, when you can make your meaning clear by saying (b) "You ate the food I ordered" or "You've eaten my meal!" or (c) "I've ordered the same as you", or "I'm having the same thing".

We disambiguate these by context and convention. If you say to the waiter "I'll have what he's having" they understand that you want to order the same thing, not that you're going to eat off his plate. For the latter meaning you say "I'm going to share his food."

Common sense also comes into it. If two people at a function are "wearing the same dress" it must mean that they're wearing different instances of the dress, as two people can't wear the same item at the same time.

@Barmar Are you sure?

@Henry Brings new meaning to "who wore it better?"

Following on from Barmar's comment, I'd say only logicians would entertain 2a and 2b meaning anything other than "I ordered X, and you ate it!" 2c defaults to "I ordered the food that you then ate"; the other reading would be more naturally "I ordered what you did". 2d sounds unnatural anyway. Pragmatics as well as strict logic and common sense needs to be considered.

Depends on the verb, and thus the noun that is involved with that verb, and the resulting semantics. What you're saying is what they're saying, just in different words..
